# How would you find someone with expertise on selling to Patent Assertion Entities?

Tags: patent-infringement, licensing, litigation, enforcement, commercial-use

I've tried googling all sorts of different sentences trying to find information on PAEs. Nothing that comes up is of any use.

Here is my situation:
My patent was granted in 1 country, pending in several more. However there is at least 1 company who has come out and announced a product that would infringe my claims. There are several more who have hinted towards doing it.

Now I would like to approach them about licensing. However it is very likely (IMHO) based on my initial impression from preliminary discussions that they are going to say things like "You don't have the money to enforce."

Obviously I am not looking for any concrete answers on what to do. However I am looking for a theoretical framework with which I can reason about my options.

I would imagine that there is some sort of advisors who advise people on how to deal with these situations. However I cannot find them.

Comment: I would start with a patent attorney, maybe at a big full service firm.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of this, but you might be able to find a lawyer who will represent you on contingency. That is they earn maybe 30% of whatever they negotiate in licensing fees or lawsuit awards.

Comment: @George White I asked my lawyer who is at a big firm, he didnt have much to say.

Comment: googling "patent broker" brought up a few things that looked relevant.

Comment: Thanks George, It looks like "Patent Broker" is the correct term. Before I was searching "Agent" and getting the wrong results.

Comment: By coincidence, I am a patent agent. A patent agent is a registered USPTO practitioner who is *not* also a licensed attorney in at least one state. All registered practitioners have the same rights ,privileges and responsibility in regard to proceedings at USPTO.  I had not heard of it either until about a year before I passed the patent bar and became one.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to share with a lawyer any posible profit from suing , you can pay an Intellectual property insurance and it will cover the process (depending on the total insured)
Note: it will protect you over future infringements (not those happening right now, I think none yet, correct ?)

There are affordable offers in the market

Comment: This is new to me. Are there any web links you could give that provide more information?

Comment: Hi Eric, there are many providers, in US / UK / ES 

UK:
https://www.cipa.org.uk/ip-insurance/
https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/867476/List-of-Insurance-Providers-2020.pdf

US: (non exhaustive list :)
patentinsurance.com (they have affordable packages)
etc..

search for "intellectual property insurance"

Comment: Thank you. I looked into that before. Am I correct that they cover the majority of the litigation costs but not the entirety? Do you know what percentage coverage is possible?

Comment: All depends on the terms , I saw one covering for example up to 1.5 million , you don’t need to pay anything over, check with them , ask

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to suggest it, but you could look into [Intellectual Ventures](https://www.intellectualventures.com). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_Ventures):

> Intellectual Ventures is an American private equity company that
> centers on the development and licensing of intellectual property.
> Intellectual Ventures is one of the top-five owners of U.S. patents,
> as of 2011. Its business model focuses on buying patents and
> aggregating those patents into a large patent portfolio and licensing
> these patents to third parties. The company has been described as the
> country's largest and most notorious patent trolling company, the
> ultimate patent troll, and the most hated company in tech.